# What renders faster, pre-defined image alpha, or opacity?

Tags: css, performance, web, png, transparency

If I have a `png` image that is 127 alpha, and I have the same image with normal alpha (255) and a CSS style of `opacity:0.5`, which will render faster?

The reason I'm asking is I want a few partially transparent clouds in a webgame, and I'm interested to know which is a better technique to put less strain on the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PNG will do better.

To render element with opacity < 1.0 the browser will 1) create bitmap buffer, 2) render your image there and then 3) render that buffer to the target.

With PNG it will do just #3.

Particular details may vary but these steps will be there in one form or another.